# webpack execute module in global scope

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there any way to have webpack execute module in the global scope? Specifically, my use case is the following library:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/master/lib/adal.js

where there is the following code:

```
var AuthenticationContext;
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports.inject = function (conf) {
        return new AuthenticationContext(conf);
    };
}
```

As you can see the module is exporting an injection function (not sure why they don't just export the class). I am able to construct a new AuthenticationContext object successfully using the using the injection function. However, some of the functionality in this library relies on a global AuthenticationContext class and it errors out when window.AuthenticationContext === undefined. I would like to bundle this module with webpack but somehow, I need to ensure that AuthenticationContext will be available in the global scope. Is there any way to do that?

I have read about the ProvidePlugin but, as I understand the ProvidePlugin just takes an exported value and attaches it to the global scope. In this case I need to ensure that a non-exported value will be available in the global scope.

The most obvious solution is just to execute this module in the global scope. However, I would like this module to be part of the bundle. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved this with the following code:

```
import {inject} from 'adal-angular/lib/adal.js';
import config from './auth-config';

export default class Authenticator {
    constructor() {
        this.authContext = inject(config);
        window.AuthenticationContext = this.authContext.constructor;
    }
}
```

basically, I am exposing the constructor manually.